# CSS - Weird White-Space In Border of Image

Tags: html, css

I have two images that I gave borders to (1px solid black), but in my browser they are rendered with a weird white-space - kind of like an involuntary padding.

The white space is on one side only, but depending on the zoom it can change the side of the border (e.g. suddenly the "pseudo-padding" is no longer on the right, but on the top), or even on two sides at the same time.

```css
.img img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section class="imgrid">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" />
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" />
  </div>
</section>
```

That's about it in terms of relevant code. The images are 500px squares (so 500x500).

Edit: This has nothing to do with the suggested 'similar question' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256). I have already tried vertical align before I created this question. I have added width: 100% and vertical-align: middle to the snippet to illustrate this.

The problem looks like so:

[on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX3o1.png) [image]

[at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgICG.png) [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: No, not it. Thanks, though.

Comment: @caramba Please remove the "possible duplicate" OR prove to me how the answer to my question is provided in your suggestion.

Comment: I don't see any white space...post a image and also which browser you are using?

Comment: Try using a CSS reset stylesheet. You can also try using `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }` at the top of your CSS as a quick test. Browsers may add extra styling to your page. E.g. Chrome adds a 8px margin to the body tag.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions! I am using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115, and I have already reset the padding and margin, also using box-sizing: border-box! I am out of answers for this absurd phenomenon :/

Comment: I didn't downvote but thought it could be a duplicate. Those links are just here to help. They don't have anything to do with the downvotes.

Comment: Can you please also show a image of the "involuntary padding". I'm also using chrome and don't see any.

Comment: Well then I am sorry. I am just frustrated with people downvoting for no apparent reason - it's not helping anyone. I will provide you with an image, sure: http://i.imgur.com/0hH5R3B.png - on the right. http://i.imgur.com/eYt8aUK.png - at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem if you look here: https://jsfiddle.net/0t4vLky7/ ?

Comment: Yes. What the hell is wrong with my browser if I am the only one getting that problem O.o

Comment: Does it occur with no zoom? Like if no zoom. On OSX press CMD+SHIFT+0

Comment: Not sure what no zoom is (other than the obvious not having zoomed in). I am not using zoom and it still creates this horrible space that's there out of nowhere...

Comment: So if I zoom in after a few steps this can happen. Not sure if it's a browser bug or a monitor/graphic card bug. No zoom === not zoomed in && not zoomed out . So if no zoom I don't see it. Most people zooming have issues with the eyes so they want see it :)

Comment: Here's a screenshot with the chrome inspector/devtools (whatever it's called) http://i.imgur.com/t7rWGR2.png - I think that kind of shows what the problem is, but I still do not understand it

Comment: In my case it was only visible on QHD monitor.

Comment: I hope this helps and and align with what you are experiencing [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: I've used 0.5px instead of 1px for border width.

Answer (score 11):

Pretty sure if you're seeing this you have a 4k screen set to something other than 100% scaling.

I have two 4k screens, one set to 100% (my laptop screen) and another set to 125% (because it is physically bigger so needs scaling).

Here's a couple images with borders on my 4k laptop screen. The scale factor is 100% so everything is clean:

[image]

And then moved over to my external screen. This has DPI setting of 125% (in Windows). In the browser it's 100% scaling, but it's the DPI setting that causes this effect:

[image]

With a circle the effect is worse and you end up with a shape that isn't even completely round.

[image]

Clearly with 125% scaling a one pixel line will be scaled to 1.25 pixels, which to requires either sub pixel rendering (anti-aliasing) or just snapping to the closest pixel. It seems they don't consider image + 1 pixel border as a single entity and rounding errors are what ultimately gives this behavior.

The fix of setting the background color to the same as the border color sort of works, but you end up with this:

[image]

I think the important thing to realize is that it won't affect most people.

Another possible solution is to add an absolute div on top the same width and height and set the border on that. Make sure `box-sizing: border-box` is set. That will ensure the border is exactly on top of the image. However I **don't** recommend this in general because it will quickly become unmanageable.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem (using Chrome) and came across this thread.

None of these answers helped me, but I found that adding a `background-color` that matches the border color to the `img` element resolved the problem for me:

```
img {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: The ```background-color``` property has no effect on ```img``` tag for me. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on Chrome, I had to make sure the browser was on 100% zoom and that fixed it for me. Chrome likes to round px measurements without your consent, and that can lead to weird styles when you zoom in or out.

Answer (score 4):

none of them worked for me in Chrome under Windows, but setting `margin: -1px;` on the img did the trick

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem developing a website when noticed some of the images had a tiny gap underneath.

The box on the left has the fix applied, the right one not:
[image: Strange Gap Phenomenom]

I found *a* "fix" **only for Chrome**:

Adding `vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;` to the `img` element seemed to remove it.

Comment: Thank you! No clue what is going on here, but I could have sworn this was not normal behavior in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I'am not wrong adding `width: 100%;` to image will solve the issue.

Comment: Cool, so should I use both width: 100%; AND width: 100% tho?

Comment: max-width/min-width will not do anything if width is set to some fixed value. so it is better to remove max-width;

Comment: Alright, I see. But 100% width didn't solve it unfortunately. Still thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Margin and padding should remove the white border that you see I hope this helps!

```css
img {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px ;
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Still looks messed up in my browser. Which is weird, since I am using a not-so-old version of Chrome... Thanks, anyways!

Comment: can you take a screen shot of your screen for us to see.. and try using Google chrome developer tools ("Ctrl+Shift+I")to see where that white padding is coming from. @Joe

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vvCxFlA.jpg - no padding at all, no margins either. I made sure of that

Comment: I noticed different css then what you posted here on the question, would it possible if you can post you css for us to really understand and see your css code, Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with the CSS I posted here. And I don't see why it's happening, there's nothing telling the browser to create padding or anything

Comment: use my css code aand also you have (.img img {}) , remove the .img @Joe

Comment: .img img is intentional. .img is the class I used for the divs in which I have the images (img).

Comment: I understand but as an experiment, lets try it out, .img is the class but img refers to the actual img @Joe

Comment: If I remove the specifications on the .img then the whole thing becomes different.

Comment: well the next step i would say is for you to post your full project css and html like that i can see if maybe something else i causing the white border and or if its just your browser, and i know your frustrated this kind of stuff has happened to me in the past, it just takes time well figure it out!

Comment: please approve or vote my answer if i was able to help, if not please let me know what problem is still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help and align with what you are experiencing right now: [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

**Explanation: why is there a gap under the image?**
The gap or extra space under the image isn't a bug or issue, it is the default behaviour. The root cause is that images are replaced elements (see MDN replaced elements). This allows them to "act like image" and have their own intrinsic dimensions, aspect ratio....
Browsers compute their display property to inline but they give them a special behaviour which makes them closer to inline-block elements (as you can vertical align them, give them a height, top/bottom margin and padding, transforms ...).

This also means that:

> `<img>` has no baseline, so when images are used in an inline formatting context with vertical-align: baseline, the bottom of the image will be placed on the text baseline.
> (source: MDN)

As browsers by default compute the vertical-align property to baseline, this is the default behaviour. The following image shows where the baseline is located on text:

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCUJm.png)

According to this thread there are different ways to fix this gap:

- Set the vertical-align property of the image to `vertical-align: bottom;` `vertical-align: top;` or `vertical-align: middle`;
- Set the display property of the image to `display:block;` -- This is the most effective way so far.
- Setting `line-height:0;` or `font-size:0;`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29656602)

Comment: @slideshowp2 done putting some references according to the same thread mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fixing it with a shadow instead. This removed the white space for me on both my 4k montior and my FullHD laptop.

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
```